# how can i define iframe to have null content?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have this code and I want after every click the content of the iframe will be null and only later

```
<div id="code" contenteditable></div>
<iframe id="output"></iframe>
<button onclick="update()">run</button>

<script>
function update() {
var frame = document.getElementById("output");
var frameDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
var w = document.getElementById("code").textContent;

//************************************
//here is what i want to change
frame.contentWindow === null;
frame.contentWindow.document.write(w);
//************************************
}
</script>
<style>
#code{
width:47%;
height:81.8%;
border:1px solid;
}
#output{
width:47%;
height:80%;
border:1px solid;
position:absolute;
right:0px;
top:0px;
}

</style>
```

Thank you so much for the help (-;

p.s.- I try to make my editor

Comment: You need to do `frame.contentWindow.document.close();`after each write, then the next write will clear it. Also why not use frameDoc now you have it? Also make the button `type="button` some browsers will submit the page if not

Comment: Your own var: `var frameDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;`

Comment: thanks!! it's work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
frame.contentWindow.document.close();
```

after each write, then the next write will clear it.

Also why not use frameDoc now you have it?

```
function update() {
  var w = document.getElementById("code").textContent;
  var frame = document.getElementById("output");
  var frameDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
  frameDoc.write(w); 
  frameDoc.close(); 
}
```

Also make the button `type="button` some browsers will submit the page if not